# Prove that the set of points $(x, y, z)$ satisfying $y^2=4x$ is a regular surface.

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry

Prove that the set of points $(x, y, z)$ satisfying $y^2=4x$ is a regular surface.

**This is the surface?**

[image]

You can see that it is regular, but now, how do I prove it?

The surfaces are: $\{(x, y, z)\in \mathbb{R}^3|y^2=4x\}$

But we can see it in the following way: $\{(\frac{y^2}{4}, y, z)\in \mathbb{R}^3\}$

How do I show that this set is a regular surface?

I don't know if this is correct: The surface can be seen as $\phi (u, v)=(\frac{u^2}{4}, u, v)$ which is differentiable; then $\phi _u = (\frac{u}{2}, 1, 0)$ and $\phi _v=(0,0,1)$, and so $\phi _u \times \phi _v = (1,-\frac{u}{2},0)\neq 0$. I can already conclude that it is a regular surface?

Comment: I believe that is only part of tle plot. And I believe you should use definition of regular surface instead of words "you can see".

Comment: @IvanKaznacheyeu I don't know if this is correct: The surface can be seen as $\phi (u, v)=(\frac{u^2}{4}, u, v)$ which is differentiable; then $\phi _u = (\frac{u}{2}, 1, 0)$ and $\phi _v=(0,0,1)$, and so $\phi _u \times \phi _v = (1,-\frac{u}{2},0)\neq 0$. I can already conclude that it is a regular surface?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is an extruded prismatic surface.

If curve f(x,y) =0 is a regular parabola in the plane, then parabolic cylindrical surface f(x,y) =0 is also regular.

Comment: Could you be more explicit? So that way, I can understand it better. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I mean the curve is just an intersection, a subset, has to be as regular, what else could it be?